Is it possible to fully replicate the default behavior of git log with a format string?
To learn the limits of git log format strings, I decided to see if I could replicate git log default output using a format string.
So far I have:
git log --format='%C(auto)commit %H%d%nAuthor: %an <%ae>%nDate:   %ad%n%n%w(0,4,4)%s%n%n%-b%-C()%n'

Unfortunately, there are still two differences I have observed:

In my output, the ref names output by %d are added unconditionally, while git log will suppress them when the output is a file, and shows them when the output is a terminal.
In my output, I sometimes see a raw ^M symbol in commit messages, but it seems like git log output does not show this output.

Is it possible to correct for either or both of these differences, or is this the closest I can get with a custom format string?

They really should document what the default formatting is. If you can use --format and get the same result. Because you sometimes want the default but with a little tweaking.

Totally agreed! I started down this rabbit hole because I couldn't find it documented anywhere. Maybe I'll post an issue on the project.

You could try looking at the code, maybe for slight variations like pretty format fuller. It might be that those built-in, named pretty formats are implemented in terms of a formatting string.

My current opinion from looking at the code is that the answer is "No".
Also, linking my post to the mailing list: https://lore.kernel.org/git/CAO8bsPDiVLei4uc96jv2BnhQapo2NaFLu-MbdBMmdCKVtFuyZA@mail.gmail.com/T/#t
